# jq error when looping through array: Cannot index array with string "<key>"

Tags: json, linux, bash, shell, jq

I'm tryng to iterate over all element contain in the `all` index. Here is my json string :

```
{  
   "all":[  
      {  
            "id":"51a"
      },
      {  
            "id":"52b"
      },
      {  
            "id":"53c"
      }
    ]
}
```

I have tried to iterate with `jq` :

```
for id in $(jq '.all.id | keys | .[]' <<< "$json"); do
    echo "$id"
done
```

But I get this following error :

> jq: error (at :9): Cannot index array with string "id"

I expect to get the following output :

```
51a
52b
53c
```

Comment: `while IFS= read -r id; do ...; done < <(jq ...)` is a better way to run that loop. Right now, if you have an id of `*`, a list of filenames in your current directory will be inserted (among other issues; consider that one a representative example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like that:

```
for id in $(jq -r '.all[].id' <<< "$json"); do
    echo "$id"
done
```

Notice that `-r` option has to be used if you want to remove double quotes:

> ```
>  ·   --raw-output / -r:
>
>        With this option, if the filter´s result is a string then
>        it will be written directly to standard output rather than
>        being formatted as a JSON string with quotes. This can be
>        useful for making jq filters talk to non-JSON-based
>        systems.
> ```

The entire script could look like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

json='{  
   "all":[  
      {  
            "id":"51a"
      },
      {  
            "id":"52b"
      },
      {  
            "id":"53c"
      }
    ]
}'

for id in $(jq -r '.all[].id' <<< "$json"); do
    echo "$id"
done
```

But as noted in the comments, `for x in $(...)` is an antipattern and should not be used: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor.

To assign two indices to 2 separate variables:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

json='{
   "all":[
      {
            "id":"51a",
            "name":"Steve"
      },
      {
            "id":"52b",
            "name":"Phoebe"
      },
      {
            "id":"53c",
            "name":"Dino"
      }
    ]
}'

jq -r '.all[] | .id + " " + .name' <<< "$json" |
    while read -r id name; do
        echo id: "$id"
        echo name: "$name"
    done
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer ! I have found a workaround https://www.pastiebin.com/5ce29e47a50c5 but I'm going to use the code in the answer

Comment: I'd like to know if it's possible to also extract an other element from the same array. Let's say I have id and name index with their value. How can I extract both ?

Comment: @executable: `jq` is a fairly simple tool. It defines expressions to extract parts of the input, and a syntax to assemble the output. `.all[].id` is shorthand for `.all | .[] | .id`, and you want another member in addition to `.id`. So how should that second member be combined with `.id` ?

Comment: @executable: It could be something like this: `for id in $(jq -r '.all[] | .id + " " + .name' <<< "$json"); do`

Comment: @Arkadiusz Drabczyk Thank you for the answer but is it possible to assign them separatly to variable ?

Comment: @executable: You mean 2 variables - for example `id` and `name`?

Comment: @Arkadiusz Drabczyk yes, so I can play with them

Comment: This answer is great from a `jq` perspective, but in bash, `for anything in $(...)` is an antipattern. See [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: correct, that's way I switched from it to `jq ... | while read ...`.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk, ...not completely, however -- you still have the old pattern shown. Note that we don't ask people to leave in "Edit:" markers here in SO; the history is visible to anyone who clicks the link to see it, so it's most important that an answer be complete, collect and useful to people reading it top-to-bottom for the first time.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: ok, I removed EDIT marker. I switched to `jq ... | while read ...` to be able to operate on full lines as they are returned by `jq`. Could you explain how to do that correctly?

Comment: Yes, that code's great; point is you're using it in only one of two places. The code *before* the edit marker you removed was still showing the `for x in $(...)` idiom.

Comment: BTW, in deciding whether to pipe *to* your loop or redirect to the loop from a process substitution, see [BashFAQ #24](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Answer (score 1):

and here's an alternative solution based on a walk-path unix tool for JSON: **[`jtc`](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc/blob/master/User%20Guide.md)**:

```
bash $ for id in $(jtc -qq -w'[all][:][id]' <<< "$json"); do  echo "$id"; done
51a
52b
53c
bash $
```

PS> Disclosure: I'm the creator of the `jtc` tool

Comment: What's different from `jq` ?

Comment: tools are drastically different. jq is a processor with own DSL with the scope of operations well beyond JSON data model. While jtc is a utility confined to the data model operations only. That difference let coming up with queries to manipulate source jsons a lot easier (but of course it's mho).